# ¿Como puedo regresar al primer menú en un Switch?

Tags: java, switch, bluej

Estoy haciendo una práctica de la escuela, se trata de un menú & diversos submenus simulando una interfaz de registros de usuario para una escuela, el registro de alumnos funciona, sin embargo, no sé como regresar de un submenu al menú principal o que al terminar de "registrar" un alumno me vuelva a mostrar las opciones del submenu.

Básicamente lo que quisiera es que al terminar de registrar un "Alumno" muestre de nuevo las opciones y no solo se cicle el programa o se cierre como si ya hubiése terminado.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

A continuación mi código

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class sistema
{
    public static void main()
    {
        int principal;
        
        System.out.println("Bienvenido");
        System.out.println("1. Registro de Profesores");
        System.out.println("2. Registro de Alumnos");
        principal = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Seleccione una opción"));
        
        if(principal == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Ha ingresado al modo de Administrador");
        }
        
        switch (principal){
            //do{
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Bienvenido Profesor");
            break;
            
            case 2:
                int opcion;
                boolean salir = false;
                
                System.out.println("Bienvenido Alumno");
                System.out.println("1. Registrarse");
                System.out.println("2. Verificar Inscripción de Materias (Solo para usuarios registrados)");
                System.out.println("3. Verificar Calificación de Materias");
                System.out.println("4. Regresar");
                opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Seleccione una opción: "));
                
                switch (opcion) {
                
                      case 1:
                          
                        System.out.println("Opción " + opcion + ": Registro de Alumnos");
                        
                        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
                        Alumno a[] = new Alumno[1];
                        
                        String nombre = "";
                        String apellido = "";
                        String semestre = "";
                        String carrera = "";
                        int no_control = 0;
                        
                        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Ingresa tu nombre: ");
                            nombre = leer.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Ingresa tu apellido: ");
                            apellido = leer.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Ingresa tu Semestre: ");
                            semestre = leer.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Ingresa tu Carrera: ");
                            carrera = leer.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("Ingresa tu No. de control: ");
                            no_control = leer.nextInt();
                            
                            System.out.println("Usuario registrado con éxito");
                            leer.nextLine();
                            
                            a[i] = new Alumno(nombre, apellido, semestre, carrera, no_control);
                        }
            
                        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Nombre" + " " + "Apellido" + " " + "Grupo" + " " + "Materia" + " " + "No. Control");
                            System.out.println(a[i].getNombre()+" | "+a[i].getApellido()+" | "+a[i].getSemestre()+" | "+a[i].getCarrera()+" | "+a[i].getNoControl());
                        }
                        
                        break;
                
                      case 2:
                        System.out.println("Opción: " + opcion);
                        break;
                
                      // match the value of week
                      case 3:
                        System.out.println("Opción: " + opcion);
                        break;
                        
                    }
            break;
            case 3:
                int pregunta;
                
                LocalDate diaActual = LocalDate.now();
                System.out.println("Using username: ubuntu");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Authenticating with public key imported-openssh-key");
                System.out.println("Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1052-aws x86_64)");
                System.out.println("System information as of " + diaActual);
                System.out.println("ubuntu@ip-172-31-82-81:~$");
                pregunta = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Seleccione una opción: "));
            break;
            
            default:
            System.out.println("No existe la opción " + principal + ". Selecciona una nueva.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes meter todo en un `while` y poner una variable para cerrar el programa

```
int principal;
boolean cerrar;
while(!cerrar) {
       
    System.out.println("Bienvenido");
    System.out.println("1. Registro de Profesores");
    System.out.println("2. Registro de Alumnos");
    System.out.println("4. Cerrar programa");
    principal = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Seleccione una opción"));
    ...

    case 4:
        cerrar = true;
}
```

Básicamente esto lo que hace es entrar en el loop hasta que `cerrar` sea `true` y esto solo ocurre cuando se aprieta la opción 4.

En caso de que entre al submenú, el submenú y el `case 2` terminará y regresará automáticamente al menú principal.